# Finding the mean of $\big(\sum^{n}_{j=1}{X_{ij}}\big)^2$ where $X_{ij}$ is an indicator variable

Tags: algorithms, self-learning

Let $n_i$ be the random variable denoting the number of elements placed in bucket $B[i]$ and let $X_{ij}$ be the indicator variable $\mathbb{I}\{A[j] \text{ falls in bucket } i\}$.

Thus, for each $i$, defining $n_{i} := \sum^{n}_{j=1}{X_{ij}}$, we have

$$\mathbb{E}[n^2_i] = \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sum^{n}_{j=1}{X_{ij}}\right)^2\right].$$

Then I got confused by the two equations below. I don't know how they had this

- $\mathbb{E}[n^2_i] = \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sum^{n}_{j=1}{X_{ij}}\right) \left(\sum^{n}_{k=1}{X_{ik}}\right)\right]$
- $\mathbb{E}[n^2_i] = \mathbb{E}\left[\sum^{n}_{j=1}X_{ij}^2   + \sum_{1\leq j\leq n}{X_{ij}}\sum_{1\leq k\leq n,j \neq k}{X_{ik}}\right]$

Please can someone explain to me how they manage to get the two equations above

Comment: Can you please double-check that you meant the squares in the bullet points to be there?

Comment: @Bob I have corrected it

Comment: If $S:= \sum_{j=1}^n X_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n X_{ik}$, then the first bullet point is simply $E[S^2] = E[S \cdot S]$. I think the second bullet point has a typo; the second term should be something like $\sum_{1 \le j \le n} \sum_{k \ne j} X_{ij} X_{ik}$.

Comment: @angryavian I get it. But why not sum over j but rather over j then k ?

Comment: check now if that was what you meant

Comment: The reason why they want to use two different indices $j$ and $k$ is because when multiplying the two sums together it is necessary to distinguish the terms from the first sum and the terms from the second sum. The second bullet point looks good to me now.

Comment: Also note that $X_{ij}^2=X_{ij}$ because $X_{ij}$ is an indicator varaible.

Comment: @RobPratt Okay thanks

Answer (score 1):

The probability backdrop of this is actually irrelevant, as this is purely about symbolic algebra. First,
$$
\left(\sum^{n}_{j=1}{X_{ij}}\right)^2=\left(\sum^{n}_{j=1}{X_{ij}}\right)\left(\sum^{n}_{j=1}{X_{ij}}\right)=\left(\sum^{n}_{j=1}{X_{ij}}\right)\left(\sum^{n}_{k=1}{X_{ik}}\right)
$$
where the 2nd equality above is just changing the dummy counter from "$j$" to "$k$" for the second summation. Second, as for why:
$$
\left(\sum^{n}_{j=1}{X_{ij}}\right)\left(\sum^{n}_{k=1}{X_{ik}}\right)=\sum^{n}_{j=1}X_{ij}^2   + \sum_{1\leq j\leq n}{X_{ij}}\sum_{1\leq k\leq n,j \neq k}{X_{ik}}
$$
you just have multiply out the LHS:
$$
\left(\sum^{n}_{j=1}{X_{ij}}\right)\left(\sum^{n}_{k=1}{X_{ik}}\right)=\sum^{n}_{j=1}\left[{X_{ij}}\left(\sum^{n}_{k=1}{X_{ik}}\right)\right]=\sum^{n}_{j=1}\left[X_{ij}^2+X_{ij}\left(\sum_{1\leq k\leq n, k\neq j}{X_{ik}}\right)\right].
$$